# Error executing Process Builder

Tags: apex, visualforce, workflow, flow, process-builder

While executing a `Process Builder`, I am receiving the following error:

> Error Occurred: UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS :
>   (INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY) You can not update fields except
>   RTime and Itime on a child event.

Comment: Can you include any detail about the process itself?

Comment: It is basically saying that you cannot update the fields you are attempting to update. The fields must be create() but not update()

Comment: Do you have admin privileges? Can you grant yourself read/write privileges to the object? Is that in line with the organisation's data policy?

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission error it would seem...

Process Builder runs as the RUNNING USER.  If you want to do it via Process Builder then you need to modify your system's permissions.

If you need to bypass that and run as system, you can do that in a Flow triggered by a Process Builder.